# Count number of rows between time intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with start and end times (datetime.time) for a list of processes:

```
from datetime import time
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['start', 'end'], 
                  index=pd.Index(['proc01', 'proc02'], name='Processes'), 
                  data=[
                        [time(10), time(14)], 
                        [time(12), time(16)]
                  ])
```

I want to transform this info into a histogram that counts how many processes are running:

```
>>> bins = pd.date_range('08:00', '22:00', freq='1H').time
>>> count_processes(df, bins)
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I have an implementation but it's kinda slow for big dataframes (around 2~3 million rows), I would like to know if there's a way to vectorize it or at least make it more fast:

```
def count_processes(df, bins):
     result = np.zeros_like(bins, dtype=int)
     for _, row in df.iterrows():
         aux = (row['start'] <= bins) & (bins < row['end'])
         result += aux.astype(int)
     return result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating over a Dataframe is usually a sign you're not using `pandas` optimally. You could instead substract the processes that have ended from the processes that have started, like this:

```
res = []
for b in bins:
    s = (df['start'] < b).sum()
    e = (df['end'] < b).sum()
    res.append(s-e)
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Uisng `numpy` boardcast , unfortunately this is O(m*n) solution , try with your real data , if you have any problem with it, please let me know

```
v1=pd.to_datetime(df.start,format='%H:%M:%S').values
v2=pd.to_datetime(df.end,format='%H:%M:%S').values
bins=pd.to_datetime(bins,format='%H:%M:%S')
np.sum(((v1-bins[:,None])<=np.timedelta64(0,'ns'))&((v2-bins[:,None])>np.timedelta64(0,'ns')),1)
Out[529]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```